# Auto increment ID using OleDb to excel

Tags: vb.net, auto-increment

I want to Auto increment The ID when I Add new data in my excel file. whats wrong in this code the error says"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'MAX [ID]'"

```
Dim Value As Integer
    cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "C:\\Users\\Barbatos\\Desktop\\Book3.xlsx " + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    cm = New OleDbCommand("SELECT MAX [ID] FROM [Sheet1$]", cn)'error here
    cn.Open()
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        Value = dr(0)
    Else
    End If
    dr.Close()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`MAX` is a function so you need to have the argument(s) in parentheses:

```sql
SELECT MAX([ID]) FROM [Sheet1$]
```